# Cannot boot from GParted usb drive

Tags: boot, usb, gparted

I ran GParted from this USB drive on another desktop, so I know it's not the fault of the USB drive.

I get the main boot screen asking me to confirm loading up Gparted.

If I choose any of the options (including failsafe) I get the following error message:

```
unload module index
modprobe: can't load module ntfs (kernel/fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko): Invalid argument
calling: test-builtin
load module index
unload module index
modprobe: can't load module ntfs (kernel/fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko): Invalid argument
modprobe: can't load module ntfs (kernel/fs/ntfs/ntfs.ko): Invalid argument
calling: test-builtin
load module index
```

This text then repeats.

Any ideas?

I tried a few other Linux distros, but no luck. None of the others gave much of an error message, and GParted is the distro I need.

[image: error message]

Comment: What was the operating system of both systems? and how was the gparted usb device created? I was thinking bios/uefi

Comment: It worked on a Windows 7 + bios system. It won't work on a Windows 8 MBR system.

Comment: Is secure boot turned on ?

Comment: Secure boot is switched off.

Comment: Is the ntfs.ko module actually present?  Were there messages that indicated that any other kernel modules loaded successfully?

Comment: @Vamsi if it's got as far as the kernel trying to load modules, then it's gotten past secure boot.

Comment: No other messages loading modules. Anyway, I ran out of time on this, so I unplugged the drive and took it over to the other machine and formatted it there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If Gparted bootable drive is not working then you can try Ubuntu live usb to use Gparted. Not to mention it will take more space in your usb drive but not a bad option in emergency, Eh?

Comment: Strangely I couldn't get that working either. I think it must be a problem with UEFI/BIOS. Anyway, problem solved now, so I'll worry about this another time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you boot from the flashdrive in UEFI mode. If you load the boot menu at the start, choose the flashdrive boot in legacy mode and will be fine. In the boot menu the flashdrive should appear twice, once in UEFI once in Legacy. Usually the UEFI is the default.